# Explain steps please

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain the steps here? A is a matrix with only 1's as elements:

$\left( {\rm I}_n - \frac{1}{n-1}A \right)({\rm I}_n - A) = {\rm I}_n - \frac{1}{n-1} A - A + \frac{1}{n-1}A^2 = {\rm I}_n - \frac{n}{n-1} A + \frac{n}{n-1}A = {\rm I}_n.$

How does he get rid of the $-A $ in the middle and how does he just plug $n$ in the denominator?

I realize $J^n = nJ$ but $J \neq nJ$ so why does he plug $n$ in both?

Comment: You combine the $-A$ with the term to the left of it. And it's not $J^n=nJ$, it's $J^2=nJ$.

Comment: $$\frac 1 {n-1} A + A = \frac A {n - 1} + \frac {An - A} {n - 1} = \frac {An} {n - 1} = \frac n {n - 1} A$$

Comment: T.....hank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the common denominator ,

$$ - \frac{1}{n-1}A - \frac{n-1}{n- 1}A = - \frac{n}{n- 1}A $$